# Buscar Archivo en Directorio Java

Tags: java

Quiero mediante un método encontrar la ruta en la que se encuentra un archivo en cualquier lugar de C:

He probado con el siguiente codigo, y para ahorrar tiempo el archivo esta en: `C:\ficheros\subcarpeta\archivo.txt`

```
public static void encontrarRuta(String directorio, String busqueda){

    File f = new File(directorio);

    if(f.isDirectory()){

        File[] list = f.listFiles();

        for (File file : list) {     
            System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
            encontrarRuta(file.getAbsolutePath(), busqueda);
        }
    }else{
        if(f.getName() == busqueda){
            RUTA_ENCONTRADA = f.getAbsolutePath();
            System.out.println(RUTA_ENCONTRADA + "sisisisi");
        }
    }
}
```

El problema es que si pongo como Directorio inicial `C:\\` hay `NullPointerException.`

Si solo pongo `C:\\ficheros\\` lista correctamente todo el directorio pero no muestra el `sout` del interior del ultimo if, por lo que supongo que no entra.

He probado también... Pero no me lista los archivos solo directorios.

```
public static void encontrarRuta(String directorio, String busqueda){

    File f = new File(directorio);

    if(f.exists()){

        File[] list = f.listFiles();

        for (File file : list) {

            if(file.isDirectory()){
                System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
                encontrarRuta(file.getAbsolutePath(), busqueda);
            }else{
                if(file.getName() == busqueda){
                    System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath() + "ENCONTRADO");
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Gracias.

Comment: Aunque para la primera parte, también te interesa leer https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/42977/cu%c3%a1l-es-la-soluci%c3%b3n-a-todos-los-errores-nullpointerexception-presentes-pasados/42978#42978

Comment: En general, te será más fácil obtener ayuda si planteas tus problemas en términos más específicos ("¿por qué no me entra en este `if`?") que si lo haces en términos de lo que hace tu programa ("buscar archivo en directorio")